# Название модуля в 1С-Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс, модули

Выручайте! Уже не знаю в какую сторону копать. Публикую свое решение в marketplace.bitrix.

При установке решения пишет: Установка модуля "Веб-формы"

Хотя в install/index.php в конструкторе класса все верно прописано:

```
$this->MODULE_NAME = "Правильное название";
```

Откуда берется название "Веб-формы" - ума не приложу. Поиск по всему модулю такой фразы вообще не нашел. В списке модулей после установки название выводиться корректно. Проблема только при установке и удалении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, нашел проблему. GetMessage("FORM_INSTALL_TITLE") был уже занят модулем Веб-формы из за этого и получилась накладка.